# how to bypass firebase functions cold start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am using the firebase Stripe API, and what is happening is my app doesn't have a lot of traffic yet, nor will it for a little while. Firebase decided, after 2-3 minutes of no invocations on the function, it goes into cold start mode. This is unfortunate because it means my wait time from when a new user hits register, and goes to the checkout page, it is like 8 seconds. How horrendous is that!

Anyways, does anyone know a way around this, maybe setting a script to run in the background at all times, or something I can do from inside firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to help is to add a "cold-start" command to the Cloud Function (i.e. a "no-op" invocation/call), and invoke it when your user starts the checkout process (before collecting any information).  If the User doesn't complete check-out, no-harm-no-foul; if they *do*, the cloud function has already been started.

Update 2020-01-01:
Firebase now allows you to designate for each function, in the console, a *minimum* (and/or maximum) number of invocations - i.e. keeping functions in memory.  A single active function costs about $0.33 to $0.50 per month - a fairly low (but not zero) cost for keeping cold starts down...

Comment: that sounds pretty interesting. Is there a way to do this from inside the firebase console?

Comment: No, we're talking *code* here - *your* code, and the Cloud Function code.  It *is* **YOUR** code, right?

Comment: In the code for your Cloud Function (the Stripe function), you add some type of argument you can give it that doesn't actually *do* anything.  In your client code (whether web or mobile) you insert a call to the Cloud Function, using the No-Op argument just described.  That call will fire up the Cloud Function, leaving it in memory.  Your user will take some amount of time to finish checkout; then the client code makes the "real"call to the Cloud Function which has *already* "cold-started".

Comment: This doesn't *eliminate* the cold-start; it just *hides* it while your user is busy doing other things - at the cost of an extra invocation of your function.